# AJAX not working submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I got some `AJAX` code, but it doesn't get response from server. I tried many things but can't figure out why this is not working. I am running on a `localhost` setup with `XAMPP`. I want the `echo` to be seen in the `span` with id status.

**AJAX on index.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registrationform").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            data: $("#registrationform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#status").html(data);
            }
        });

        alert("Ajax not running")
        });
});
```

---

**FORM on index.php**

```
<form id="registrationform" action="">
Voornaam: <input type="text" name="voornaam" /><br />
Tussenvoegsel: <input type="text" name="tussenvoegsel" /><br />
Achternaam: <input type="text" name="achternaam" /><br />
Geslacht: <?php include_once("parser/geslacht.php"); ?><br />
Land: <?php include_once("parser/land.php"); ?><br />
Geboortedatum: <?php include_once("parser/gebdatum.php"); ?><br />
E-mail: <input type="text" name="e-mail" /><br />
Wachtwoord: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
Hertype wachtwoord: <input type="password" name="password2" /><br /><br />
De onderstaande vraag is nodig om uw wachtwoord terug te halen mocht u die vergeten zijn.<br />
Geheime vraag: <select name="geheimevraag" id="geheimevraag">
<option value="huisdier">Wat is de naam van jouw eerste huisdier?</option>
<option value="moedername">Wat is de meisjesnaam van je moeder?</option>
<option value="eerstebaas">Hoe heet je eerste baas?</option>
<option value="eigenvraag">Eigen vraag opstellen</option>
</select><br/>
<span id="anders" style="display:none;">Eigen vraag: <input type="text"  name="eigen_vraag" style="width:300px;"/></span><br  />
Antwoord: <input type="password" name="gantwoord" /><br />
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<span id="status"></span>
```

---

**registration.php**

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
echo "There is a value";
}else{
echo "enter a value";
}
?>
```

Comment: i think your form is still posted (reloading the site) because your eventhandler doesnt return false

Comment: add a callback for 'failure' in your $.ajax call, as the ajax method will fail silently unless you write something to handle any errors. that is probably what is happening. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: There are now 3 Answers if they dont , change url: "registration.php" to correct url 'like_http://localhost:8080:/*something*/registration.php'

Comment: use event.preventDefault();,May your form was submiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**write the `<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>` before `</form>` close tag**

```
 <form id="registrationform" action="">
    Voornaam: <input type="text" name="voornaam" /><br />
    Tussenvoegsel: <input type="text" name="tussenvoegsel" /><br />
    Achternaam: <input type="text" name="achternaam" /><br />
    Geslacht: <?php //include_once("parser/geslacht.php"); ?><br />
    Land: <?php //include_once("parser/land.php"); ?><br />
    Geboortedatum: <?php //include_once("parser/gebdatum.php"); ?><br />
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="e-mail" /><br />
    Wachtwoord: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    Hertype wachtwoord: <input type="password" name="password2" /><br /><br />
    De onderstaande vraag is nodig om uw wachtwoord terug te halen mocht u die vergeten zijn.<br />
    Geheime vraag: <select name="geheimevraag" id="geheimevraag">
    <option value="huisdier">Wat is de naam van jouw eerste huisdier?</option>
    <option value="moedername">Wat is de meisjesnaam van je moeder?</option>
    <option value="eerstebaas">Hoe heet je eerste baas?</option>
    <option value="eigenvraag">Eigen vraag opstellen</option>
    </select><br/>
    <span id="anders" style="display:none;">Eigen vraag: <input type="text"  name="eigen_vraag" style="width:300px;"/></span><br  />
    Antwoord: <input type="password" name="gantwoord" /><br />

   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <span id="status"></span>
```

Your jquery script script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#registrationform").submit(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();    
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registration.php",
    data: $("#registrationform").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
    $("#status").html(data);
   }
});

 alert("Ajax not running")
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: write the <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> before </form> close tag

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registrationform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            data: $("#registrationform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#status").html(data);
            }
        });

        alert("Ajax not running")
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the default behavior of the submit button

```
$("#registrationform").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Then you need to implement a proper failure handler, your current one will allways alert because that ajax is async

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registration.php",
    data: $("#registrationform").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // check your console to see if request is success and what it contains
        $("#status").html(data);
    }
}).fail(function () { 
   alert("oh noes"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the form so that the page won't change location, and so that JS can do the AJAX request.

```
$("#registrationform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this one
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registration.php",
        data: $("#registrationform").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#status").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```